# Combine list of numpy arrays and reshape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm hoping anybody could help me with the following.
I have 2 lists of arrays, which should be linked to each-other. Each list stands for a certain object. `arr1` and `arr2` are the attributes of that object. 
For example:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = [np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 2]), np.array([2, 3])]
arr2 = [np.array([20, 50, 30]), np.array([50, 50]), np.array([75, 25])]
```

The arrays are linked to each other as in the `1` in `arr1`, first array belongs to the `20` in `arr2` first array. The result I'm looking for in this example would be a numpy array with size 3,4. The 'columns' stand for 0, 1, 2, 3 (the numbers in arr1, plus 0) and the rows are filled with the corresponding values of arr2. When there are no corresponding values this cell should be 0. 
Example:

```
array([[ 0, 20, 50, 30],
       [ 0, 50, 50,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 75, 25]])
```

How would I link these two list of arrays and reshape them in the desired format as shown in the above example?

Many thanks!

Comment: There is no number `0` in `arr1`.

Comment: @Dschoni The question states : `When there are no corresponding values this cell should be 0`.

Comment: @Divakar: The question states: "The columns stand for 0,1,2,3 (the numbers in arr1)"

Comment: @Dschoni Hmm, well that should be a typo. Good catch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an almost* vectorized approach -

```
lens = np.array([len(i) for i in arr1])

N = len(arr1)
row_idx = np.repeat(np.arange(N),lens)
col_idx = np.concatenate(arr1)

M = col_idx.max()+1
out = np.zeros((N,M),dtype=int)
out[row_idx,col_idx] = np.concatenate(arr2)
```

*: Almost because of the loop comprehension at the start, but that should be computationally negligible as it doesn't involve any computation there.

Comment: @cf2 No problem! Maybe edit the question to clarify that doubt on `0` in `arr1`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with for-loops. Showing each step in detail.

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = [np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 2]), np.array([2, 3])]
arr2 = [np.array([20, 50, 30]), np.array([50, 50]), np.array([75, 25])]

maxi = []
for i in range(len(arr1)):
    maxi.append(np.max(arr1[i]))
maxi = np.max(maxi)
output = np.zeros((len(arr2),maxi))
for i in range(len(arr1)):
    for k in range(len(arr1[i])):
        output[i][k]=arr2[i][k]
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the details of each step. Very useful!

Answer (score 0):

This is a straight forward approach, with only one level of iteration:

```
In [261]: res=np.zeros((3,4),int)
In [262]: for i,(idx,vals) in enumerate(zip(arr1, arr2)):
     ...:     res[i,idx]=vals
     ...:     
In [263]: res
Out[263]: 
array([[ 0, 20, 50, 30],
       [ 0, 50, 50,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 75, 25]])
```

I suspect it is faster than `@Divakar's` approach for this example.  And it should remain competitive as long as the number of columns is quite a bit larger than the number of rows.